# iText + GAE : How create random URL?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, itext

sorry for my bad english. I'm using iText in GAE + GWT.. i made a example app and it works in google! but i have a problem whit the token of URL.

I have this RPC service which create the Document in a Array of Bytes and write this in the HttpSession, then in client onSuccess block i call a Servlet which send to the client the PDF . The `String token = "258958395ai53"` is a token where the client find the PDF but in this example y made the token static so i need to create the token randomly and make sure that the token don't repeat. Here is de code.

RPC Service:

```
public String getPdf() {
    Document document = new Document();
    String token = "258958395ai53";
    // generate test PDF
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("¡HOLA PUTO MUNDO!"));
        document.close();
        byte[] pdf = baos.toByteArray();
        HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute(token, pdf);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("ReportServlet::generatePDF::Exception "
                + e.getMessage());
    }

    return token;
}
```

Servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // create output stream from byte array in session
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String token = request.getParameter("token");
        byte[] pdf = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute(token);
        baos.write(pdf);

        // setting some response headers
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0,pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        // content length is needed for MSIE
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());

        // write ByteArrayOutputStream to ServletOutputStream
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        baos.writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
}
```

onSuccess:

```
                public void onSuccess(String lista) {
                    String token =  lista;
                    //Window.open("hello?token="+ token, "_blank","menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
                    Dialog d = new Dialog();
                    d.setWidth(500);
                    d.setHeight(700);
                    d.setUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"hello?token="+token);
                    d.show();
                }
            });
```

Any idea? .. Can view my example http://pdfprueba2.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a random generator. There are more advanced random generators available such as SecureRandom (see [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/securerandom.shtml) how it works). On top of this you can combine multiple unique elements to create an uber unique key. [This](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1030397) article gives an overview of some of the methods used in creating such a thing.

Take in account that the more complexity you add, the more resources/time it will take.